# Android - proguard error Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

Tags: proguard

My application uses:
- actionbarsherlock
- admob
- startapp
- YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar

when I encode it using eclipse error Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
help me config file proguard.cfg

Comment: Please provide some context for your problem, please.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '{' at 'SafeParcelable' in line 57 of file 'C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android-optimize.txt'

Comment: @Vickute did you get any answer for this?